# please explain how to use paypal_adaptive gem in rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am new to ruby and I need to work with the paypal_adaptive gem.

Environment: Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.0.7

Does any one have sample code for using the paypal_adaptive gem with Rails 3?

Comment: Some [sample code comes with the gem](https://github.com/tc/paypal_adaptive). There are links there to help you get started.